# How many small squares needed to fill a rectangle?

Tags: python, puzzle

I am trying to solve a problem on codeforces. I am a beginner and I am just trying to understand how to solve this problem I do not want to copy someone's code.

Requirements are :

There is 1 big rectangle of n * m units. (n and m are length and width) and small squares of length a are suppose to fill it up.
Its okay to fill a little more are if a squares don't cover the big square (n*m) completely.

If n = 6 and m = 6. area of n*m becomes 36 units. and suppose a = 4 then each tile covers 16 units of area.

Now when we lay down small squares on big rectangle it comes to 4 small squares needed to cover big rectangle.

I can easily calculate the area of large rectangle:

```
l_area = n * m
```

area of small squares :

```
s_area = a*a
```

Now how to calculate the number of small squares needed to cover the big rectangle.

The divide operator does not work for obvious reason.

Comment: That's a math question, not a programming question. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute how many squares you need to fill up `n`, and how many to fill out `m`, and multiply.  In your example, the small square is length 4, so you need 2 for `m` and 2 for `n`, so you need 2x2 = 4 squares.

To get the number of squares for one side, you divide and round up.  One way to do this is

```
math.ceil(float(bigLen)/float(smallLen)))
```